# Create a div with an image

Tags: hyperlink, photo

I am trying to create divs from an array of links of photos. This is what the array looks like
[image]

I am trying to go through each element of the array and for each link create a photo div.
What should I use a `image.src`? I am not sure about that.

```
list.forEach((x) => {
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      image.src = ;
      image.className = "queryImg";
      document.getElementById("queryResults").appendChild(image);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also browse the links, to make sure they are image files.

```
list.forEach((x) => {
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      image.src = x;
      image.className = "queryImg";
      document.getElementById("queryResults").appendChild(image);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `image.src = x;` work?

In your `forEach`, `x` is being passed as the iterated element in the array so the actual data would be retrieved using that